# How to configure SELinux using samba? Scientific Linux?

Tags: rhel, samba, selinux

when I'm trying to mount a read-only samba share, then I get this messages on the samba server (and timeout on client side)

```
Nov  5 18:45:49 localhost kernel: type=1400 audit(1352137549.469:17): avc:  denied  { module_request } for  pid=3046 comm="smbd" kmod="net-pf-10" scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:smbd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 tclass=system
```

I already tried:

```
setsebool -P samba_export_all_ro 1
getsebool -a | egrep -i 'smb|samba'
yum install policycoreutils-python
semanage fcontext -a -t samba_share_t '/PATH/TO/SAMBASHARE(/.*)?'
restorecon -R /PATH/TO/SAMBASHARE
/etc/init.d/smb restart
```

How can I configure SELinux to allow the read-only samba share? Turning off SELinux is just idiotic.

UPDATE:

```
[root@SERVER ~]# getsebool -a|grep -i smbd
allow_smbd_anon_write --> off
[root@SERVER ~]# setsebool -P smbd_disable_trans 1
libsemanage.dbase_llist_set: record not found in the database
libsemanage.dbase_llist_set: could not set record value
Could not change boolean smbd_disable_trans
Could not change policy booleans
```

Comment: OK. You can try to disable SELinux particularly for SMB service. Use `smbd_disable_trans` variable... In this case another protections of SELinux are still active.

Comment: there isnt a boolean named smbd_disable_trans

Comment: Very strange... Look here please: http://kangry.com/topics/viewcomment.php?index=18546

Answer (score 1):

It appears that smbd is trying to autoload the kernel module `net-pf-10`, which is an alias for `ipv6`. This apparently isn't permitted in SELinux, since it wasn't reasonably anticipated that the module *wouldn't* be loaded (or that you would ask for IPv6 bindings with IPv6 disabled).

There are at least two possible ways to resolve this.

1. Re-enable IPv6 system-wide (since you almost certainly disabled it; this is just one of many problems that disabling IPv6 will cause).
2. Re-configure Samba to not attempt to bind to any IPv6 address. Change the `interfaces` line in `smb.conf` to bind to your desired IPv4 addresses only. An example:

   ```
   interfaces = 127.0.0.1 198.51.100.87
   bind interfaces only = yes
   ```